# ICM broadcast case list search

Tags: javascript, dojo, filenet-p8, ibm-case-manager

I'm trying to preview similar IBM Case manager cases when a case is opened, I'm getting error onBroadcastEvent is not a function it is not included inside self. I'm using wiring to the script adapter (send work Item)

```
require(["icm/model/properties/controller/ControllerManager", "ecm/model/Desktop" ], function(ControllerManager, Desktop) {

  var solution = Desktop.currentSolution;   
  var params = {};  
  var self = this;    

  var prefix = solution.prefix;    

  params.ObjectStore = solution.getTargetOS().id;    

  var custID = payload.workItemEditable.propertiesCollection.LSS_IdentificationValue.value;

  console.log ("Customer ID: ",custID);    

  var caseObj = payload.workItemEditable.icmWorkItem.caseObject;    

  caseObj.retrieveCachedAttributes(function(caseObject) {      

  var caseID = caseObject.caseIdentifier;      

  console.log ("Case ID: ",caseID);        

  /* Find all of these */      

  var criterion1 = new ecm.model.SearchCriterion({"id": prefix+"IdentificationValue", "name" : "Identification Type", "selectedOperator": "STARTSWITH", "defaultOperator": "STARTSWITH", "dataType": "xs:string"});      

  criterion1.value = custID ;      

  criterion1.defaultValue = custID ;      

  criterion1.setValues( [custID]);        

  params.criterions = [criterion1];      

  params.CaseType = ""; /* all case types */      

  params.solution = solution;        

  var searchPayload = new icm.util.SearchPayload();      
  searchPayload.setModel(params);        
  searchPayload.getSearchPayload(function(payload) {          
  self.onBroadcastEvent("icm.SearchCases", payload);      
  });  

  });            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "this" in "var self = this;" resides in an anonymous function, therefore this is probably the Window object.

Do i understand correctly that this code-block is in a scriptadapter? In that case, move your assignment to the first line, before your require. Then your self will the the scriptadapter (that has the onBroadcastEvent function on it).

```
  var self = this; 
  require(["icm/model/properties/controller/ControllerManager", "ecm/model/Desktop" ], function(ControllerManager, Desktop) {

  var solution = Desktop.currentSolution;   
  var params = {};
  ....
```